# how to tidy up a large dataframe with the tidyr tool

Tags: r, sorting, tidyverse, tidyr

Currently, I have this wide dataframe.

```
> dput(head(data))
structure(list(Host.H = c("Human", "Human", "Human", "Human", 
"Human", "Human"), Seq_ID.H = c(">H3-USA", ">H3-USA", ">H3-USA", 
">H3-USA", ">H3-USA", ">H3-USA"), Start = c(1L, 121L, 161L, 401L, 
721L, 1081L), End = c(160L, 240L, 280L, 520L, 1040L, 1280L), 
    Strand.H = c("Forward", "Forward", "Forward", "Forward", 
    "Forward", "Forward"), P.H = c(0.995962, 0.985782, 0.997249, 
    0.983122, 0.998574, 0.993674), Locus_ID.H = c("id \"locus1\"", 
    "id \"locus5\"", "id \"locus7\"", "id \"locus8\"", "id \"locus10\"", 
    "id \"locus12\""), Host.I = c(NA, "Intermediate", NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), Seq_ID.I = c(NA, ">I3-MM-CHA", NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    Strand.I = c(NA, "Forward", NA, NA, NA, NA), P.I = c(NA, 
    0.988441, NA, NA, NA, NA), Locus_ID.I = c(NA, "id \"locus5\"", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), Host.B = c(NA, "Bat", "Bat", "Bat", "Bat", 
    NA), Seq_ID.B = c(NA, ">B2-RS-CHA", ">B2-RS-CHA", ">B2-RS-CHA", 
    ">B2-RS-CHA", NA), Strand.B = c(NA, "Forward", "Forward", 
    "Forward", "Forward", NA), P.B = c(NA, 0.987457, 0.997273, 
    0.975433, 0.998187, NA), Locus_ID.B = c(NA, "id \"locus7\"", 
    "id \"locus9\"", "id \"locus10\"", "id \"locus11\"", NA), 
    Host.C = c(NA, "Consensus", "Consensus", "Consensus", "Consensus", 
    NA), Seq_ID.C = c(NA, ">I3-MM-CHA", ">I3-MM-CHA", ">I3-MM-CHA", 
    ">I3-MM-CHA", NA), Strand.C = c(NA, "Forward", "Forward", 
    "Forward", "Forward", NA), P.C = c(NA, 0.98647, 0.997287, 
    0.981532, 0.998712, NA), Locus_ID.C = c(NA, "id \"locus7\"", 
    "id \"locus9\"", "id \"locus10\"", "id \"locus12\"", NA), 
    Type = c("Unique", "Conserved", "Shared", "Shared", "Shared", 
    "Unique")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I've been looking for a method to tidy this data. To perform this, I need all the columns with the suffix (.H, .I, .B, and .C) to be grouped in each column as follows (Host, Seq_ID, Start, End, Strand, P, Locus_ID and Type).
Note that the values of "Type" must be distributed according to the assigned value corresponding to each row, I explain with the following example of the desired output

```
Host         Seq_ID     Start    End     Strand      P     Locus_ID      Type
Human       >H3-USA      1      160      Forward    0.99   id "locus1"   Unique
Human       >H3-USA      121    240      Forward    0.98   id "locus5"   Conserved
Intermediate>I3-MM-CHA   121    240      Forward    0.98   id "locus5"   Conserved
Bat         >B2-RS-CHA   121    240      Forward    0.98   id "locus7"   Conserved
Consensus   >I3-MM-CHA   121    240      Forward    0.98   id "locus7"   Conserved
Human       >H3-USA      161    280      Forward    0.99   id "locus7"   Shared
so on...
```

Then I'd like to summarize if the "Start" and "End" position is the equal, as long as the "Host" is the same.

I have tried to use the "pivot longer" function but have not been able to get it to work. For this reason, I hope you can collaborate with me. I would be very appreciated with you

Comment: Hello, and welcome!  Kindly use `dput()` to provide reproducible data when asking a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hi, I agree with your suggestion, but in this case by using dput() the data doesn't look nice because the dataframe is too wide and too big

Comment: Why not just `dput(head(data))`?

Comment: Please check my edited post

Comment: You can `pivot_longer()` as follows: `data %>% pivot_longer(cols = !c(Start, End, Type), names_sep = "\\.", names_to = c(".value", NA))`.  If you want to track the suffix  (`"H"`, `"B"`, etc.) of the original column (`Host.H`, `Host.B`, etc.), use `names_to = c(".value", "Suffix")` in your `pivot_longer()` call, which will give you a `Suffix` column in addition to the existing columns in your sample output.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying this statement: _"Then I'd like to summarize if the "Start" and "End" position is the equal, as long as the "Host" is the same."_.

Comment: Your script worked very well for me, what could be further implemented to delete the rows that have missing data as N.A.? Other hand, I mean that for case, in "Human" there are two or three times repeated positions of "Start and "End" that they can be summarized in only one. Example: Host = Human, Start = 44, End = 86; Host = Human, Start = 44, End = 86; Host = Human, Start = 44, End = 86, summarize in a single row: Host = Human, Start = 44, End = 86. The rule is the following: they must have the same "Host" and "Type" for summarizing them

Comment: I'll type up a brief solution, though I do suspect it's just a composite of many other solutions available on SO.

Comment: You're right. I'm not sure if it'll work by employing group by and summarize functions

Comment: When you say _"summarize"_, do you mean to _aggregate_ values in other columns (like taking the `mean()` of `P` values) within that group, or do you simply mean to take the _first_ row in that group.

Comment: It means to take the row of the first group. As long as the duplication of the "Start" and "End" positions in the same "Host" and "Type" is fulfilled.

Comment: Let me know if [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68214709) works for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution in the [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/), which leverages `dplyr` in general and `tidyr::pivot_longer()` specifically:

```
library(tidyverse)


# ...
# Code to generate 'data'.
# ...


data_2 <- data %>% pivot_longer(# "Unpivot" all columns except these:
                                cols = !c(Start, End, Type),
                                # Uses regex lookaround to target the last ".",
                                # used to separate column prefixes from suffixes.
                                names_sep = "\\.(?!.*\\.)",
                                # "Unpivot" to consolidate columns with the same
                                # prefix, and then record the suffixes in a new
                                # 'Suffix' column.
                                names_to = c(".value", "Suffix")) %>%
  # Remove rows with missing 'Host'.
  filter(!is.na(Host)) %>%
  # Within each group of 'Host' and 'Type', select only the first row with each
  # combo of 'Start' and 'End'.
  group_by(Host, Type, Start, End) %>% filter(row_number() == 1) %>% ungroup() %>%
  # Select the columns in proper order.
  select(Host, Suffix, Seq_ID, Start, End, Strand, P, Locus_ID, Type) %>%
  # Sort as desired.
  arrange(Start, End) %>%
  # Convert back into data.frame, if desired.
  as.data.frame()


# Print the results.
data_2
```

Given a dataset `data` like the example you provided

```
data <- structure(list(Host.H = c("Human", "Human", "Human", "Human", "Human", "Human"),
                       Seq_ID.H = c(">H3-USA", ">H3-USA", ">H3-USA", ">H3-USA", ">H3-USA", ">H3-USA"),
                       Start = c(1, 121, 161, 401, 721, 1081),
                       End = c(160, 240, 280, 520, 1040, 1280),
                       Strand.H = c("Forward", "Forward", "Forward", "Forward", "Forward", "Forward"),
                       P.H = c(0.995962, 0.985782, 0.997249, 0.983122, 0.998574, 0.993674),
                       Locus_ID.H = c("id \"locus1\"", "id \"locus5\"", "id \"locus7\"", "id \"locus8\"", "id \"locus10\"", "id \"locus12\""),
                       Host.I = c(NA, "Intermediate", NA, NA, NA, NA),
                       Seq_ID.I = c(NA, ">I3-MM-CHA", NA, NA, NA, NA),
                       Strand.I = c(NA, "Forward", NA, NA, NA, NA),
                       P.I = c(NA, 0.988441, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                       Locus_ID.I = c(NA, "id \"locus5\"", NA, NA, NA, NA),
                       Host.B = c(NA, "Bat", "Bat", "Bat", "Bat", NA),
                       Seq_ID.B = c(NA, ">B2-RS-CHA", ">B2-RS-CHA", ">B2-RS-CHA", ">B2-RS-CHA", NA),
                       Strand.B = c(NA, "Forward", "Forward", "Forward", "Forward", NA),
                       P.B = c(NA, 0.987457, 0.997273, 0.975433, 0.998187, NA),
                       Locus_ID.B = c(NA, "id \"locus7\"", "id \"locus9\"", "id \"locus10\"", "id \"locus11\"", NA),
                       Host.C = c(NA, "Consensus", "Consensus", "Consensus", "Consensus", NA),
                       Seq_ID.C = c(NA, ">I3-MM-CHA", ">I3-MM-CHA", ">I3-MM-CHA", ">I3-MM-CHA", NA),
                       Strand.C = c(NA, "Forward", "Forward", "Forward", "Forward", NA),
                       P.C = c(NA, 0.98647, 0.997287, 0.981532, 0.998712, NA),
                       Locus_ID.C = c(NA, "id \"locus7\"", "id \"locus9\"", "id \"locus10\"", "id \"locus12\"", NA),
                       Type = c("Unique", "Conserved", "Shared", "Shared", "Shared", "Unique")),
                  row.names = c(NA, -6L),
                  class = "data.frame")
```

you should get output for `data_2` like this:

```
   Start  End      Type Suffix         Host     Seq_ID  Strand        P     Locus_ID
1      1  160    Unique      H        Human    >H3-USA Forward 0.995962  id "locus1"
2    121  240 Conserved      H        Human    >H3-USA Forward 0.985782  id "locus5"
3    121  240 Conserved      I Intermediate >I3-MM-CHA Forward 0.988441  id "locus5"
4    121  240 Conserved      B          Bat >B2-RS-CHA Forward 0.987457  id "locus7"
5    121  240 Conserved      C    Consensus >I3-MM-CHA Forward 0.986470  id "locus7"
6    161  280    Shared      H        Human    >H3-USA Forward 0.997249  id "locus7"
7    161  280    Shared      B          Bat >B2-RS-CHA Forward 0.997273  id "locus9"
8    161  280    Shared      C    Consensus >I3-MM-CHA Forward 0.997287  id "locus9"
9    401  520    Shared      H        Human    >H3-USA Forward 0.983122  id "locus8"
10   401  520    Shared      B          Bat >B2-RS-CHA Forward 0.975433 id "locus10"
11   401  520    Shared      C    Consensus >I3-MM-CHA Forward 0.981532 id "locus10"
12   721 1040    Shared      H        Human    >H3-USA Forward 0.998574 id "locus10"
13   721 1040    Shared      B          Bat >B2-RS-CHA Forward 0.998187 id "locus11"
14   721 1040    Shared      C    Consensus >I3-MM-CHA Forward 0.998712 id "locus12"
15  1081 1280    Unique      H        Human    >H3-USA Forward 0.993674 id "locus12"
```

Comment: Great! It was the results I was aiming for. I greatly appreciate your support

Comment: Glad to hear it, @DiegoMunoz!